# How can I convert kernel quantiles into sample quantiles?

Tags: quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function, kernel-smoothing

I calculated the quantiles for an Epanechnikov kernel which I'm using to estimate the density of a sample. What I need is to find the sample quantiles knowing that it is composed of many Epanechnikov kernels. Is there a way to calculate at wich data points the different quantiles are using the kernel inverse CDF formula?

Comment: If you mean that you have a density function expressed as a linear combination of Epanechnikov densities and you wish to compute its quantiles directly using the inverse CDF, the answer is no in general.  (Conceivably some special configurations of data--equal spacing comes to mind--could be amenable to such an approach.)  You're best off integrating your density using the CDF of the kernels and numerically finding its quantiles.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.uv.es/~bernardo/Kernel.pdf)  may be useful as a "structural" guide to what you want to do, but you will need to adapt it to the particular distribution you used.  It uses a normal mixture, rather than a Epanechnikov mixture